# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}x^{n}(1-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Convergence of the series $w_n = (-1)^{n}x^{n}(1-x)$ on $(0,1)$, then $\sum w_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Idea : I wanted to use the M-test for convergence of series,so I found out the value of x for which $w_n$ is maximum on (0,1) but the value comes as an expression in n where the sign of the such an x also depends on n, so I am stuck here.

Is the direction of my approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Weierstraß' M-test here: $\lvert w_n(x)\rvert$ has a maximum $M_n$ for $x=\dfrac n{n+1}$ and this maximum is 
$$M_n=\Bigl(\frac{n}{n+1}\Bigr)^n\Bigl(1-\frac n{n+1}\Bigr)\le\frac1{n+1}.$$
Now *Leibniz's test for alternating series* says the remainder at rank $n$ satisfies
$$\lvert R_n(x)\rvert\le\lvert w_{n+1}(x)\rvert\le M_{n+1}=\frac1{n+2},$$
which proves the convergence is uniform on $(0,1)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i did manage till $M_n$ but cant that expressions' convergence be ascertained by any other method apart from leibnitz test?

Because this test has not been taught to us in our college.

Comment: Ok I studied about Leibnitz test for alternating series ...it requires the participating sequence $u_n = {(\frac{n}{n+1})}^n (1-\frac{n}{n+1})$ to be monotone and $lim u_n \rightarrow 0$. How do you show the later part?

Comment: Do you mean monotonicity or the $0$ limit?

Comment: 1) Why is the leibnitz test for series relavent as $M_n$ is a series of positive terms? Isnt the test meant for series of alternating terms?

2) How would you show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @spaceman_spiff: I apply Leibniz' test to $\text{boldmath}w_n(x)$, not to $M_n$: $x^n(1-x)$ is indeed a decreasing function of $n$ for  each $x\in(0,1)$, and it does tend to $0$. $M_,$ is here only to obtain a bound on the remainders.